# How to make a heading transition from bottom to top using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

In that program, I want H1 to be animatedly come from the bottom hidden position using CSS transition at the time of loading, so how do I do that?
For bounding height, it should be fixed, and also text is popping up from the bottom hidden position in CSS. What would be the best approach to doing that?
The code is given below.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" id="heading">
      <div className="bounding">
        <h1 className="boundingelem">Product</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and css also given

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1;
}
.bounding {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 150px;
}
.bounding .boundingelem {
  transform: translateY(10%);
}
.bounding .boundingelem::before {
  content: "Product";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can animate transform through a transition:

```
.bounding {
  ...
  position: relative;
}

.bounding .boundingelem {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.bounding .boundingelem .show {
  ...
  transform: translateY(-150px);
}
```

You just have to add the class `show` to h1 whenever you want this transition to occur on load.

-> This suggested change interferes with your `transform` css though as I have no idea why you have `transform: translateY(10%)`. You have a fixed height of the container element `bounding` of `150px` so setting `top: 150px` will have it hidden intially and then `translate(-150px)` will unhide it on load.